# scrollHeight gives incorrect value when height property is provided in css

Tags: html

I tried to get the scrollHeight of my div and I am getting it right but when I add height property in the css for that particular div I am getting a different value.

Just run the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eagf7/25/) and you will see in console value of scrollheight property to be equal to 268 (which is equal to the sum of the heights of all the children)

but when I add a height value in the css (say height:50px;) the output comes out to be 252 (the difference is the margin of the last child element, I think).

can anybody please answer why there is a discrepancy ?

**Edit**
Since the question was not clear I have rephrased id. When I specify the height of parent div I get the scroll Height as 252 pixels while if I do not specify the height or set it to "auto" I get 268 pixel. I just wanted to know why margins do not collapse in the later case as well ? I am not worried about the collapsed margins but just want to know why the scroll height is different in these two scenarios ?

The answer given below is perfectly fine. However I also got the correct scrollHeight using javascript (including the bottom margin of the last child)

```
var h = $(div).height();
$(div).height("auto");
var ch = $(div)[0].scrollHeight;
$(div).height(h);
```

Comment: In my case, it was solved by not using `display: flex;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After re-reading your question I found that you're asking something else. But it's still the same answer I posted earlier.

The overall height is calculated correctly to `254px`. When you set a height explicitly that is smaller than this value, the browser calculates only `238px`. This is - like your guess - without `16px` margin on the bottom and happens because of "**margin collapsing**". The last margin is discarded because of this rule:

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

So, to fix it you could use:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Or you could use padding instead (this padding would "re-build" your margin behavior, see below for explanation):

```
p {
    padding: 8px;
}
p:first-child, p:last-child {
    padding-top: 16px;
}
```

For more information visit the MDN: [Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin_collapsing).

---

**Edit:** This was my first answer, before I re-read you question. I'll leave it here, in case somebody has a similar question and also because it leads to the same the solution.

#### This solves: Why is the height/margin of siblings not as expected?

Your height is calculated correctly. What you're facing is called: **margin collapsing**.

It means that your top and bottom margins of all your `<p>`-tags are "merged". In your case with 7 rows it means:

- 18px is the height of one row
- 16px margins on top and bottom
- top of first element and bottom of last are shown as expected
- all other margins are collapsed

and this results in:

```
  7 * 18px (height)
+ 6 * 16px (margins in-between)
+ 2 * 16px (margin top and bottom)
= 254px (exact the value calculated by the browser)
```

You can easily avoid this by using `padding` instead.

For more information visit the MDN: [Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin_collapsing).