# scrollHeight calculation is different with display:flex

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I am facing a similar issue as this question [scrollHeight gives incorrect value when height property is provided in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602914/scrollheight-gives-incorrect-value-when-height-property-is-provided-in-css)

where the scrollHeight of my element is incorrect when an explicit height is set on the element.

In my case there is no margin collapsing, but the bottom padding is collapsing.

I tried recreating that in a fiddle, and i realized that it might not have to do with the padding in my case, but the display: flex property.
Somehow the scrollHeight seems to be calculated differently when using display: flex vs when not using it.

```js
$(function() {
    console.log("test "+$(".container")[0].scrollHeight);
})
```

```css
.header {
  min-height: 48px;
  background: red;
}

.body {
  min-height: 28px;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  min-height: 36px;
  background: blue;
}

.container {
  height: 56px;
  /* remove this to see change in scroll height */
  /* display: flex; */
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Some content </div>
    <div class="body"> Body </div>
    <div class="footer"> CTA </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsz8an1r/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/3yrn6dz5/ - another example without an margins

I am not able to find any documentation to support the fact that the `display:flex` is somehow changing the calculation for `scrollHeight`. Any pointers/clarifications would be helpful.

I have tested this in Chrome 86

attaching images as some comments have suggested it might be a browser specific issue

With flex
[image]

Without flex
[image]

Comment: What do you expect as a value for `scrollHeight`?

Comment: in this case, with flex it is 152px, without flex it is 170px. I would expect it to be 170px, because otherwise any margin on my footer is ignored in scollHeight. My actual use case is a bit more involved, this is an easier reproduction.

Comment: Why do you have a fixed height on the container that is smaller than its child-elements?

Comment: it is about collapsing margin, in one case , (a flex box or a bordered box) it  will keep the bottom marginof the last element inside, else the margin is outside  https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/

Comment: I don't have any margins in this example which can be collapsed

Comment: Yes you do , margin-bottom set on every children : http://jsfiddle.net/6tqoaz45/ and http://jsfiddle.net/6tqoaz45/1/ added a background to your container.  footer is 18px . 170 - 18 = 152 ;)

Comment: oops @G-Cyrillus sorry, i have observed this behaviour without margin collapsing as well. will update the code. but if that is the point, why wouldn't it collapse without display: flex ?

Comment: because flex or grid or table display is a way to keep margin inside the container ;) alike border or padding or float

Comment: @Warden330 as said, my actual use case is a bit more involved, i animate the element from collapsed state to expanded state, so there is an initial collapsed height, and to get the expanded height i use scrollHeight and then animate till that height. There might be other ways to do that, but in this question i am looking for pointers to understand the behaviour with display flex

Comment: remove the margin-bottom of the last-child and you should not have to worry about those margins are treated ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus see this fiddle without margins: http://jsfiddle.net/3yrn6dz5/

Comment: updated my snippet to remove margins

Comment: removing height and flex gives the same value (latest window's chrome Version 87.0.4280.66  ) do you still have an issue here ?

Comment: when removing height we can expect the correct value as height becomes auto. but as said that is not my use case. 
Also, i am looking for pointers to why this behaviour is happening, instead of just looking for a workaround / hack

Comment: only changing the display: flex is what makes a difference @G-Cyrillus

Comment: might this be Browser-related as well? If i change the display:flex nothing changes with the scroll-height in the fiddle (using Edge (chrome) 87.0.664.47)

Comment: when you remove flex .. do you also remove the padding-bottom ? ;)

Comment: @Warden330 i am still seeing this in chrome 87 , did you run the fiddle after making the changes ?

Comment: got it, my mistake. Looked at the wrong thing.  In my understanding the problem is caused by the initial value of a flexbox.  flex-direction is row and flex-wrap is nowrap as initial values. So the wrapper is the element that behaves differently caused by the styling of its parent container. Im not quite sure yet how exactly but thats the culprit i think

Comment: yes thats it i think! as the wrapper gets adjusted so it + its padding fit into the .container cause of "row nowrap" for teh container you get left with the ScrollHeight of all the overflowing child elements of wrapper (48px + 28px + 36px = 112px) Because the padding is inside the .container now and has no effect on the overall height. When flex is off and the wrapper adjusts to childen-height + the padding you get (48px + 28px + 36px + 18px = 130) so the padding in this case gets added at the bottom of the overflowing wrapper instead of inside the container

Comment: So if you set flex-wrap: wrap; for .container it will be back to 130px

Comment: it also works fine if I set flex-direction: column for the container, which does not impact the padding on the cross axis. But still not satisfied with the expkanation. If flex-direction is row, and wrap is nowrap, why does the padding not get included? why is this behaviour specific to flex ?